# Problema con caracteres especiales Highcharts JS [Ubuntu]

Tags: javascript, java, highcharts, glassfish

Tengo una aplicación web en la que utilizo Highcharts. Toda la web tiene el encoding utf-8, pero al mostrar los títulos de las gráficas creadas con Highcharts me salen las tildes como muestro en la imagen. Sin embargo, si arranco la app en una máquina con Windows (utilizo Ubuntu 16.04), me los muestra correctamente. Estoy desarrollando la app con netBeans usando GlassFish Server. He probado absolutamente todo y no he sido capaz de ponerle el encoding bueno a los títulos de las gráficas. Alguna idea???

Muchas gracias.[image: Ejemplo de mal encoding en caracteres especiales.]

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes definido el encoding y qué versión de Java usas?

Comment: El encoding del proyecto esta definido en las properties, en el fichero netbeans.conf, en todos los jsp... y está definido como UTF-8. La version es 1.8.0_061

Comment: Si visualizas la aplicacion en distintas maquinas ves distintos resultados? o si despliegas la aplicacion en distintas maquinas?

Comment: Si la aplicacion la arranco en una maquina ubuntu, aparecen así los caracteres especiales, si la arranco en una máquina windows aparecen bien... Pero en el caso de ser una máquina ubuntu, sólo aparece así los nombres de las gráficas, todas las demas tildes aparecen bien... Por lo que deduzco que debe ser algo de los Highcharts.